# I create html div element, but it disappears immediately in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, appendchild, createelement

This is frustrating, I want to simply create new `input field` inside `div` on my `aspx` page when `button` is clicked. I use javascript function witch appends new child element(input field) to existing `div`. It all looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function clone() {
            var html = document.createElement("input");
            html.setAttribute("id", 1);
            html.setAttribute("name", "dejan");
            html.setAttribute("value", "some text");
            html.setAttribute("type", "text");
            document.getElementById("panj").appendChild(html);
        }

    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="panj">
                Djubrov
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="clone()" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Funny thing is that text element with set text value flashes for second when i click the button but it disappears afterwords. Do I missing something?

Comment: Why do you think that elements that are created on clientside remain after postbacks? The server does not even know that they exist and will not recreate them.

Comment: How do i then create new element when some user-inflicted-event fires, and make them visible on same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the value from this generated text field in code behind, you would be much better off not to create it dynamically via Javascript. You could just create a normal textbox and set it to be initially invisible like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="yourTextboxID" Visible="False" runat="server" />
```

When the button is pressed, handle the event in the code behind and make the textbox visible:

```
yourTextboxID.Visible = True;
```

Viewstate will keep the values across postbacks.

If each button press should create an additional textbox, you could also do this in the codebehind, i.e. use a placeholder in the ascx and then attach a new textbox to it with each button press:

```
yourPlaceholderID.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "textbox1" });
```

Answer (score 7):

Every time you click that button it will cause a postback.

Fix it by stoping postback as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="clone(); return false;" />
```

Comment: This is working. But how do I make text field be visible in pages source?

Comment: Try using the innerHTML property: document.getElementById('tes_div').innerHTML = '<input></input>';

Answer (score 1):

Your button engenders a request to the server, and the ensuing response is overwriting the page with a new HTML document. Return `false` from the JavaScript function to prevent the `asp:Button` postback:

```
function clone() {
    // your above code
    return false;
}
```

and modify the button like

```
OnClientClick="return clone()"
```

If your `asp:Button` does not require interaction with the server, consider making it a `<button>` or `<input type='button' />`.

Comment: I tried with false, but that make no difference.
 Actualy I created this exapmle just to figure how to do something else. 
In real world I will have buttons on page, and when user clicks on them I will pick up corresponding name, use the name in database to select appropriate element, and then display new divs filled with information from database.

Comment: @stanislav You'll have to change from `clone()` to `return clone()`. see update

Comment: Ok, that is doing the trick. But now how can I use value of generated text field in code behind (C#)?